# installing opcache in diy openshift cartridge

Tags: php, apache, opcache

I need to run Apache and php with opcache module so i am using this codes to install apach&php in DIY openshift cartridge :

```
#!/bin/sh

    PYTHON_VERSION="2.7.4"
    VIRTUALENV_VERSION="1.9.1"
    PCRE_VERSION="8.32"
    NGINX_VERSION="1.2.2"
    MEMCACHED_VERSION="1.4.15"
    HTTPD_VERSION="2.4.18"
    APR_VERSION="1.5.1"
    ZLIB_VERSION="1.2.8"
    PHP_VERSION="5.5.9"
    XDEBUG_VERSION="2.2.3"
    APC_VERSION="3.1.13"


    OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR=$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/runtime
    OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR=$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/runtime/repo
    Current_DIR="$PWD"
echo $Current_DIR

echo "Prepare directories"
cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR
mkdir srv
mkdir srv/pcre
mkdir srv/httpd
mkdir srv/php
mkdir tmp
rm -rf $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/*

cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/

echo "Install pcre"
#if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/pcre/bin" ]; then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/
    wget ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}.tar.gz
    wget http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/exim/pcre/pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}.tar.gz   
    tar -zxf pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}.tar.gz
    cd pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/pcre
    make && make install
    cd ..
#fi
echo "Install Apache httpd"
#if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/httpd/bin" ]; then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/
    #wget http://www.dsgnwrld.com/am//httpd/httpd-${HTTPD_VERSION}.tar.gz
    wget https://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-${HTTPD_VERSION}.tar.gz
    tar -zxf httpd-${HTTPD_VERSION}.tar.gz
    #wget http://apache.petsads.us//apr/apr-${APR_VERSION}.tar.gz
    wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-${APR_VERSION}.tar.gz
    tar -zxf apr-${APR_VERSION}.tar.gz
    mv apr-${APR_VERSION} httpd-${HTTPD_VERSION}/srclib/apr
    #wget http://artfiles.org/apache.org/apr/apr-util-1.5.3.tar.gz
    wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-util-${APR_VERSION}.tar.gz
    tar -zxf apr-util-${APR_VERSION}.tar.gz
    mv apr-util-${APR_VERSION} httpd-${HTTPD_VERSION}/srclib/apr-util
    cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/httpd-${HTTPD_VERSION}
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/httpd \
    --with-included-apr \
    --with-pcre=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/pcre \
    --enable-so \
    --enable-auth-digest \
    --enable-rewrite \
    --enable-setenvif \
    --enable-mime \
    --enable-deflate \
    --enable-headers
    make && make install
    #nohup sh -c "make && make install"  > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/Apach_install.log 2>&1 &
    #bash -i -c 'tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/Apach_install.log '
    cd ..
#fi
#echo "INSTALL ICU"
#wget http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/50.1/icu4c-50_1-src.tgz
#tar -zxf icu4c-50_1-src.tgz
#cd icu/source/
#chmod +x runConfigureICU configure install-sh
#./configure \
#--prefix=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/icu/
#make && make install
#cd ../..

echo "Install zlib"
#if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/zlib" ]; then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/
    wget http://zlib.net/zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION}.tar.gz
    tar -zxf zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION}.tar.gz
    cd zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION}
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/zlib/
    make && make install
    cd ..
#fi

echo "INSTALL PHP"
#if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/etc/apache2" ]; then
    cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/
    wget http://ca1.php.net/get/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz/from/this/mirror -O php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
    tar -zxf php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
    rm -rf php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
    #tar -zxf php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
    cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php \
    --with-xmlrpc \
    --with-config-file-path=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/etc/apache2 \
    --with-apxs2=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/httpd/bin/apxs \
    --with-zlib=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/zlib \
    --with-libdir=lib64 \
    --with-mysql-sock=$HOME/mysql/socket/mysql.sock \
    --with-pdo-mysql \
    --with-layout=PHP \
    --with-gd \
    --with-curl \
    --with-mysqli \
    --with-pdo-pgsql \
    --with-openssl \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-soap \
    --enable-zip \
    --enable-intl 
    #--with-icu-dir=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/icu \

    make && make install
    #nohup sh -c "make && make install"  > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/php_make_install.log 2>&1 &
    #tail -f $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/php_make_install.log
    #bash -i -c 'tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/php_make_install.log'
    mkdir $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/etc/apache2
    cd ..
#fi

#echo "Install APC"
#wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-${APC_VERSION}.tgz
#tar -zxf APC-${APC_VERSION}.tgz
#cd APC-${APC_VERSION}
#$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/bin/phpize
#./configure \
#--with-php-config=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/bin/php-config \
#--enable-apc \
#--enable-apc-debug=no
#make && make install
#cd ..

echo "Install xdebug"
#if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/bin/php-config" ]; then
cd $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/
wget http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-${XDEBUG_VERSION}.tgz
tar -zxf xdebug-${XDEBUG_VERSION}.tgz
cd xdebug-${XDEBUG_VERSION}
$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/bin/phpize
./configure \
--with-php-config=$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/bin/php-config
make && cp modules/xdebug.so $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/lib/php/extensions
cd ..
#fi

# cleanup
echo "Cleanup"
rm -r $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/*.tar.gz
rm -r $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/*.tgz
rm -r $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/tmp/*
rm -rf $OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR/*

echo "COPY TEMPLATES"
cd $Current_DIR
cd ..
DIR="$PWD"


echo "COPY TEMPLATES"
cp $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/misc/templates/bash_profile.tpl $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/data/.bash_profile
python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/misc/parse_templates.py

#nohup python ${DIR}/misc/parse_templates.py    > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/parse_templates.log 2>&1 &

#python ${DIR}/misc/parse_templates.py

#cp ${DIR}/misc/templates/bash_profile.tpl $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/data/.bash_profile
#python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/misc/parse_templates.py
cp ${DIR}/misc/templates/php.ini.tpl $OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/etc/apache2/php.ini


#cat << EOF >>$OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR/srv/php/etc/apache2/php.ini

#EOF

echo "START APACHE"
kill -9 `lsof -t -i :8080`
nohup sh -c "$HOME/app-root/runtime/srv/httpd/bin/apachectl start" > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/apach_server.log 2>&1 &

#nohup sh -c "./install.sh"  > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/Apach_install.log 2>&1 &
#tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/Apach_install.log
echo "*****************************"
echo "***  F I N I S H E D !!   ***"
echo "*****************************"
```

and added this codes to httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

So how could i install opcache  manually ?!

Thanks a lot.